# How do you organize your partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I was just curious to know how you organize your partitions.

I, for instance, normally have:

C:\ -> only for the OS
D:\ -> for Apps and Games
E:\ -> Media and Documents (Personal Stuff, Movies, Series, Music, ...)

How about you?

Answer (score 1):

**Internal 7200 RPM 2.5" 320GB disk, 1 partition:**
About everything. I do not like to separate on the partition level as this will have an impact on reading performance, as an user is intended to work in his user folder there is no need for an extra partition either, a partition for applications and games is also pretty useless as you will need to re-install a lot of them and have to create any shortcuts again. Eventually you could run out of space on a partition too...

**External 7200 RPM 3.5" 2TB disk, 1 partition:**
Backups, long time storage. Again, separation can happen in the root folder. This way of organizing makes it about useless to determine the partition sizes before-hand, and you can't run out of space...

**In the future:**
My laptop has place for a second internal disk, this would be a big SSD when the time has come and I would place the OS and frequent stuff on it. Then I would separate it in three levels:
SSD (Frequent, OS + Current Work), Internal (Normal, User), Excternal (Not frequent, Backup + Storage)

Answer (score 0):

I have two 1 TB disks.

First is for OS, applications and home directories.

Second is for media and virtual machines.

I'll add a third disk (2 TB) for media soon. Then the second disk will be for VMs only.

Answer (score 0):

C:\ for Windows, most applications swap, etc
D:\ Some apps that benefit from better disk reads, Data

Note that I have separate spindles and D:\ is a RAID 1. With only 1 HDD there's no real reason to partition it.

Answer (score 0):

C:\ and / : Operating system. Try not to put many files on here

External HD: All of my files, lots of portable programs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/sda1       /               reiserfs        defaults        1   1
# since hda is the main system drive, enabling this swap partition makes for a
# slower system
/dev/sda2       swap            swap            defaults        0   0
#/dev/sata/swap swap            swap            defaults        0   0
#/dev/sata/media /usr/share/media reiserfs      defaults        1   0
/dev/cdrom      /mnt/cdrom      auto            noauto,user,ro  0   0
/dev/fd0        /mnt/floppy     auto            noauto,user     0   0
/dev/fd1        /mnt/floppy     auto            noauto,user     0   0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts          gid=5,mode=620  0   0
proc            /proc           proc            defaults        0   0
#/dev/sda1      /mnt/sda1       vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sda       /mnt/sda        vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdb1      /mnt/sdb1       vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdb       /mnt/sdb        vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdc1      /mnt/sdc1       vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdc       /mnt/sdc        vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdd1      /mnt/sdd1       vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0
#/dev/sdd       /mnt/sdd        vfat            noauto,user,sync        0   0

# same as above, but use file system buffer to perform asynchronous file operations
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/sdb1       vfat            noauto,user             0   0
/dev/sdb        /mnt/sdb        vfat            noauto,user             0   0
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/sdc1       vfat            noauto,user             0   0
/dev/sdc        /mnt/sdc        vfat            noauto,user             0   0
/dev/sdd1       /mnt/sdd1       vfat            noauto,user             0   0
/dev/sdd        /mnt/sdd        vfat            noauto,user             0   0

# experimental : shared memory
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs           size=2G,nr_inodes=5k,mode=1777 0 0
```